# The remote procedure call failed

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8.1

This is my first post, so please be easy on me :)

I am doing [a tutorial for Facebook SDK](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com/2014/12/windowsphone-store-81-facebook.html), and I am trying to login to the facebook service from a Windows Phone XAML application.
It works fine when I follow the steps of the tutorial, and hit the login button to log in, but when I am trying to automate this, I get an error.

The code uses WebAuthenticationBroker, calling `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(LoginUrl);`

When I try to put that code inside Loaded event

```cs
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.fbHelper.AccessToken == null)
    {
         WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(LoginUrl); //throws error
    }
    else
    {
        GetUserInfo();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)

I think the problem is that the page is not ready yet to perform the logic, but I don't really know where should I put the code?

Comment: Where does it exactly throw exception: when checking AccessToken, calling Broker or GettingUserInfo?

Comment: @Romasz, it's thrown in the WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(LoginUrl);

Comment: You are right, I've just tested it and indeed there is a problem, like you say. I've added a little Delay and it works fine then, but there should be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that *Broker* can be called once *Window* is activated. As I've tried it should work when done like this:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;
}

private void Current_Activated(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.Activated -= Current_Activated;
    Debug.WriteLine("Activated");
    WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(new Uri("https://google.com"));
}
```

Of course it needs some improvements, but should work. Remember only that *Activeted* event may be called for number of reasons, for example after a dialog is shown.